# Remapping [ and ] in VIM

Tags: vim, editor

I like to use { and } keys quite often in VIM because they let me navigate quickly to the next empty line or between blocks of text. However, lately I've realized it would be a lot more convenient if I didn't have to be holding the SHIFT key while I do it, so I wanted to remap { to [ and } to ] respectively. However, I've found it far more difficult to do so than I was expecting.

I've tried all sorts of nmap and nnoremap commands and none of them have gotten me the result I wanted. Does anyone know how to remap built-in vim bindings?

BTW I don't use any plugins, it is just vanilla VIM in my terminal

I've tried these commands and several variations of these commands in my ~/.vimrc with no luck:

```
nunmap [[
nunmap ]]
nmap [ {
nmap ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the things you want to "remap" are not mappings to begin with, so all you are trying to do is "mappings", not "remappings".

The following mappings "work", in `$ vim --clean`, in the sense that your cursor is moved to the expected location when you press `]`:

```
nnoremap [ {
nnoremap ] }
```

but you will notice a short delay. This delay is necessary for Vim to decide whether you really wanted `]` or one of the many commands that start with `]`.

It is possible to fine-tune that delay with `:help 'timeout'`, `:help 'ttimeout'`, `:help 'timeoutlen'`, and `:help 'ttimeoutlen'` but be aware that this is a risky path with lots of unexpected side-effects.

Now, in the general case, `:help [[` and `:help ]]` are not "mappings" so there is no point using `:help :nunmap` on them in your `vimrc`. Some filetype plugins override them with mappings, yes, but those mappings would be made *after* your `vimrc` is sourced so having those "unmappings" in your `vimrc` is utterly pointless.

What makes that *idea* even more pointless is that there are many built-in commands that start with `[` or `]` (see `:help [`), which means that you would have to override *all of them* for your scheme to have even a remote chance to work if you don't want to cut yourself from very useful things like `[D` or `[p`.

Note as well that many of those "bracket commands", like `[[`, are not restricted to normal mode, which potentially means even more mappings and even more time spent in the doc to figure it all out. That's a lot of work, with lots of hard-to-foresee side-effects, for very little gain. And did I mention `[count]`?

If I were you, I would stick with `{` and `}`.

Comment: wow, I had no idea [ and ] were used in so many commands. I agree it would be too much hassle for very little gain. But, on the plus side, I found out that I can toggle shift using 'sticky keys' on my macbook. 
So I'll just use that solution instead. Seems much simpler, and gets me what I want